# MPMoviePlayer done button Clicked Change The UIView Height

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using a MPMoviePlayer to display a video. I go into full screen and when the done button is clicked I want it to remove of the entire movie player from my view.

Right Now When I click The Done Button It Dismiss The MPMoviePlayer But It change The size Of My UIView Height. Is there any solution To remove MPMoviePlayer without affecting my View Size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a videoPlayer view controller (MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass) and add it to your root view controller.

```
videoPlayerViewController = [[VideoViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath]];
[rootViewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

then add notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopVideo:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[videoPlayerViewController moviePlayer]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopVideo:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:[videoPlayerViewController moviePlayer]];
```

then your method that gets called when the notification is received.

```
- (void) stopVideo:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[videoPlayerViewController moviePlayer]];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:[videoPlayerViewController moviePlayer]];
  MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
  [player stop];
}
```